# Qt atomic operation uses condition code register which isn't present in my MIPS 24k core

Tags: c, qt, gcc, assembly, mips

I am using a MIPS 24k core which doesn't have a FPU. I have cross compiled QT successfully and it works fine. But sometimes when it touches QBasicAtomicInt::testAndSetAcquire() defined in qatomic_mips.h , I get a SIGSEGV.

The body of the code has inline assembly language. This is the first time I'm working with it. So when I tried to find the faulty line at first, it pointed to the last line which mentions the list of clobbered registers.

Later when I took another approach, it seems to fail in the line highlighted below. Any idea what _q_value means?

```
inline bool QBasicAtomicInt::testAndSetAcquire(int expectedValue, int newValue)
{
register int result;
register int tempValue;
asm volatile(".set push\n"
             SET_MIPS2
             "0:\n"
             "ll %[result], %[_q_value]\n" //this line causes the SIGSEGV
             "xor %[result], %[result], %[expectedValue]\n"
             "bnez %[result], 0f\n"
             "nop\n"
             "move %[tempValue], %[newValue]\n"
             "sc %[tempValue], %[_q_value]\n"
             "beqz %[tempValue], 0b\n"
             "nop\n"
             "sync\n"
             "0:\n"
             ".set pop\n"
             : [result] "=&r" (result),
               [tempValue] "=&r" (tempValue),
               [_q_value] "+m" (_q_value)
             : [expectedValue] "r" (expectedValue),
               [newValue] "r" (newValue)
             : "cc", "memory"); 
return result == 0;
}
```

Disassembly:

```
00207478 <_ZN20QEventDispatcherUNIX6wakeUpEv>:
207478: 3c1c001a    lui gp,0x1a
20747c: 279c99f8    addiu   gp,gp,-26120
207480: 0399e021    addu    gp,gp,t9
207484: 27bdffc8    addiu   sp,sp,-56
207488: afbf0030    sw  ra,48(sp)
20748c: afb3002c    sw  s3,44(sp)
207490: afb20028    sw  s2,40(sp)
207494: afb10024    sw  s1,36(sp)
207498: afb00020    sw  s0,32(sp)
20749c: afbc0010    sw  gp,16(sp)
2074a0: 8c860004    lw  a2,4(a0)
2074a4: 00001821    move    v1,zero
2074a8: 24020001    li  v0,1
2074ac: c0c40768    ll  a0,1896(a2) //this is the exact line
2074b0: 00832026    xor a0,a0,v1
2074b4: 14800008    bnez    a0,2074d8 <_ZN20QEventDispatcherUNIX6wakeUpEv+0x60>
2074b8: 00000000    nop
2074bc: 00000000    nop
2074c0: 00402821    move    a1,v0
2074c4: e0c50768    sc  a1,1896(a2)
2074c8: 10a0fff8    beqz    a1,2074ac <_ZN20QEventDispatcherUNIX6wakeUpEv+0x34>
2074cc: 00000000    nop
2074d0: 00000000    nop
2074d4: 0000000f    sync
2074d8: 14800012    bnez    a0,207524 <_ZN20QEventDispatcherUNIX6wakeUpEv+0xac>
2074dc: 27b30018    addiu   s3,sp,24
2074e0: a3a00018    sb  zero,24(sp)
2074e4: 8cd00058    lw  s0,88(a2)
2074e8: 2412ffff    li  s2,-1
2074ec: 24110004    li  s1,4
2074f0: 8f99cef0    lw  t9,-12560(gp)
2074f4: 02002021    move    a0,s0
2074f8: 02602821    move    a1,s3
2074fc: 0320f809    jalr    t9
207500: 24060001    li  a2,1
207504: 8fbc0010    lw  gp,16(sp)
207508: 14520006    bne v0,s2,207524    <_ZN20QEventDispatcherUNIX6wakeUpEv+0xac>
20750c: 8f99c864    lw  t9,-14236(gp)
207510: 0320f809    jalr    t9
207514: 00000000    nop
207518: 8c430000    lw  v1,0(v0)
20751c: 1071fff4    beq v1,s1,2074f0 <_ZN20QEventDispatcherUNIX6wakeUpEv+0x78>
207520: 8fbc0010    lw  gp,16(sp)
207524: 8fbf0030    lw  ra,48(sp)
207528: 8fb3002c    lw  s3,44(sp)
20752c: 8fb20028    lw  s2,40(sp)
207530: 8fb10024    lw  s1,36(sp)
207534: 8fb00020    lw  s0,32(sp)
207538: 03e00008    jr  ra
20753c: 27bd0038    addiu   sp,sp,56
```

Comment: The GCC docs on Extended Assembly have this to say: "If your assembler instruction can alter the condition code register, add ‘cc’ to the list of clobbered registers. GCC on some machines represents the condition codes as a specific hardware register; ‘cc’ serves to name this register. On other machines, the condition code is handled differently, and specifying ‘cc’ has no effect. But it is valid no matter what the machine."  So if a "cc" clobber really causes a `SIGSEGV` (and the compiler is configured correctly for the target architecture) it might be a GCC bug.

Comment: Actually this is the first time I am coming across inline assembly code. Looking at the disassembly, I think the technique I used to find the line that causes the SIGSEGV is flawed. I used another technique, and as i stated below, the faulty line seems to be 2074ac.
Any idea what _q_value in "ll %[result], %[_q_value]\n" means?

Comment: `_q_value` is the member of `QBasicAtomicInt` that contains the value of the atomic int. The `ll` instruction is loading it into `a0` in preparation for testing it against `expectedValue` (which looks to be `0`, loaded into register `v1`).

Answer (score 1):

The MIPS CPU doesn't have a `condition code` register (an equivalent of the x86 `(E/R)FLAGS` register), so if you specify it and the code compiles, chances are, it's simply ignored. OTOH, you shouldn't have used it in the first place. I wonder if `"cc"` has a special meaning for MIPS, so far I can't find anything. Try removing `"cc"` and see if there's any change in the code or in its behavior.

`SIGSEGV` likely means that either your code is using a bad pointer, or the pointer isn't aligned properly (not a multiple of 4).

Comment: When I started to debug it first, I was also expecting it to have a bad pointer. However I found the line which was causing the SIGSEGV and it turned out to be a line from the inline assemble code in a QT header. The assembly code doesn't use any pointers. And from what I read online, if "cc" is mentioned in the list of clobbered registers, it always means Condition Code register.

Comment: How about showing us the code, where SIGSEGV occurs? Show us the source and its disassembly.

Comment: I have added the source to the question.

Comment: Now show us the disassembly of this function. `: "cc", "memory")` isn't telling us anything. You must identify the exact instruction where SIGSEGV occurs.

Comment: The Program Counter points to 2074ac which causes the SIGSEGV.

Comment: Two questions: can you access the memory contents (a word, I suppose) of `QBasicAtomicInt::_q_value` at address `a2+1896`? If you can, are you sure your MIPS processor supports `ll` and `sc`?